# $_GET['id'] returning null when passing URL with id

Tags: php, get, postman

I am new to PHP and XAMPP mySQL.
I am going through [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PM2uR_eqSvk) and I am trying to return a specific row in my DB based on the primary key - id.

However my $GET call appears to be returning null, and the else command is called returning all rows.

This is my DB, the table is named 'students':

[image: First two rows of DB]

This is my GET call:

```
//Check connection 
if ($conn -> connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " .$conn->connect_error);
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET'){
    
 
    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
        //if id not null, id used to fetch single row
        $id = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = '$id'");
        $data = $sql->fetch_assoc();
    }else{
        //else fetch all rows
        $data = array();
        $sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM students");
        while($d = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
            $data[] = $d;

        }
    }

    // Retunr json data
    exit(json_encode($data));

}
```

I am testing the $GET command in postman, the URL points to my php CRUD API in the htdocs directory of XAMMP, with the table (students) and index specified:

```
http://localhost/crud_api/api/students/1.
```

The query will a 200-OK response and return all rows in keeping with the else statement.
So my question is why is $GET['id] returning null?

Comment: Without your origin form, impossible to debug this. As a debugging tool, you could comment out the rest of your code and do `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: GET params are specified like `http://localhost/crud_api/api/app.php/students/?id=1`.

Comment: Hi, can you expand  on ‘origin form? I am using the same url in a Ionic 5 app but using postman to test the API

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL Injection - please consider using [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Thanks- but I am following a tutorial

Comment: @ZoliSzabó - with a `rewrite rule` it is perfectly valid to supply GET variables in the url as suggested in the question : ie `http://localhost/crud_api/api/app.php/students/1`

Comment: I meant replace your code in php to `<?php print_r($_GET); ?>` to see if you getting what values. Since you dont show your html form. Basic debugging with forms.

Comment: Any reason for the mark down? Feedback would be beneficial

Comment: @GetSet seems to return an empty array

Comment: Ok makes sense then nothing else works on empty array. Possibly update/edit your question with the form? You could have some discrepancies in that area of the html code.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó hi that got it thanks, do u want to post it as answer  and I will accept it

Comment: `$_GET` as empty array means there are no vars in "get". So there cant be a `do u want to post it as answer` because there is no get vars to process with logic. As such, either show the form or lets just let this sit in limbo.

Comment: @dancingbush Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**Preamble:**
GET (query params) are normally specified like this:
`https://example.com/?paramA=1&paramB=2&...paramN=X`

As @ProfessorAbronsius correctly notes in a comment, even if the "public facing" URL of a resource does not specify such parameters, these can be specified/mapped on server level, for example by using Apache's `RewriteRule` directive. *(And this is exactly the case in the tutorial linked by the OP.)*

**The problem** in this specific case seems to be that the URL used by the OP is different from the one used in the tutorial:
`http://localhost/crud_api/api/app.php/students/1` versus `http://localhost/crud_api/api/students/1`.

Please see how the tutorial defines the rewrite rules and what the URL looks like when tested in Postman:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have followed the tutorial exactly as described, the original question has been updated to reflect the same URL, the only solution that has worked is your original suggestion : http://localhost/crud_api/api/app.php/students/?id=1